# Webapp2 on GAE for session handling multiple ndb models

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, webapp2

I am fairly new to Python + GAE in general.

I need to get user session/security working properly and I followed this great instruction for webapp2:
http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/

Example Code: https://github.com/abahgat/webapp2-user-accounts

However, I cannot figure out the deviation from their example:
I have two ndb datastore kinds (two database). One for group A, one for B as in `class GroupA(ndb.model)` and `class GroupB(ndb.model)`, both slightly different fields. Like “teachers” and “students” on a single website, where "teachers" get all the students' IDs listed under "current_class".  During a login, users must specify if they are teachers or students through two simple HTML buttons.

How can I handle such session? I was following the example provided by the blog post above and what must I change? We built the project without using any session handling initially and now we are trying to add.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Datastore entities of the same kind may have a different set of properties, so there is no need to split both groups if they have only slight differences. Both teachers and students may be using the same entity kind with different properties, but need to have a common indexed property that identifies an entity as either a student or teacher. This way, any deviation from the example would be minimal.

Comment: @NikitaUchaev Thank you very much.  I appreciate your suggestion.  However, I still need help.. I see what you mean, but I am having difficulties actually implementing.  How do I expand the User model to contain both Teachers and Students data?  Students might have test scores and teachers might have office hours, students in a class, etc.  If you can point to a good reference, or provide an example, that would really be helpful.  Thanks again.